# Custom Xib Cell with Tableview isn't working

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm creating a slide out menu with xib files using the following tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Now I'm at the point to make the xib tableview view with the custom tableview cell. Reading several questions on stackoverflow I came to the following code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var nib = UINib(nibName: "MenuCell", bundle: nil)

    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "menucell")
    tableView.reloadData()

    print("count: \(animals.count)")
}
```

and the actual cell

```
extension SidePanelViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return animals.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:MenuTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("menucell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    cell.configureCell(animals[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

But the tableview is not showing the custom tableview cells with the title. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What is the name of the xib in your bundle? is it "MenuCell"

Comment: and have you mention "menucell" as identifier in attributes inspector window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have forgot to set this parameters:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```

---

As explained in comments:

Correct your class declaration like this for example:

```
class myClass: SidePanelViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { .. }
```

Comment: Where do I have to add it?

Comment: you can add it to viewDidLoad

Comment: Correct your class declaration like this for example: class myClass: SidePanelViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { .. }

Answer (score 0):

Try to cross check the following because you have added the xib explicitly in your bundle as your class name and xib name differs

**Cross check 1**

You have mentioned you custom class `MenuTableViewCell` in `Identity Inspector` window

[image]

**Cross check 2**

You have mention the cell identifier in the `Attributes Inspector` window as
[image]

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: If this helps, please accept as answer so that everyone else can know and get help instantly

Comment: See Alessandro, Correct your class declaration like this for example: class myClass: SidePanelViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { .. }